# Custom and Open Source Library Installation Fails on Databricks

Tags: installation, package, databricks, python-wheel

I'm attempting to install a custom library on databricks using the .whl file. The status of the installation hangs on pending for a few minutes before stating that it has failed. I've also tried installing a couple of open source libraries via PyPI and I'm also having the same issue. In the below image we see my custom library and xgboost have failed and pandas is stuck on pending (soon to be failed).

[image]

Can anyone help point me in the right direction for resolving this?

Comment: If you click on each of the libraries you should be able to see error messages - that might provide some hints.